# How to display data from an API in react js?

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, react-hooks, axios

Here I have a login form that I created in react js. The API I'm using gives a response as "Successful Login" or "Authentication Failed. Unable to login" depending on whether the login credentials match or not. In the login form I'm using a react hook and axios.post to send the "name" and "password" to the API. How can I also print the response I'm getting back from the API?

Here is the Login.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Button, TextField } from "@mui/material";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      password: "",
    };
  }

  changeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080/users/login", this.state)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { name, password } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Login Page</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
          <TextField
            name="name"
            label="Enter Username"
            color="secondary"
            focused
            size="small"
            variant="outlined"
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
            id="name"
            value={name}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Username"
            className="form-control"
          />
          <p />
          <TextField
            name="password"
            label="Enter Password"
            color="secondary"
            focused
            size="small"
            variant="outlined"
            onChange={this.changeHandler}
            id="password"
            value={password}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Password"
            className="form-control"
          />
          <p />
          <Button type="submit" variant="contained">
            Login
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

And here is what the console shows:

```
{name: 'Mike', password: 'password1234'}

{data: 'Authentication Failed. Unable to login', status: 200, statusText: '', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}

{name: 'Mike', password: 'Pass1234'}

{data: 'Successful Login', status: 200, statusText: '', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
```

Can I use another react hook to fetch the data? The API uses POST method so I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a very basic example of login page using hooks. In the login function, you should call the API you want and use the setResponse to display the response on the screen

```
const [Name, setName] = useState("");
const [Pass, setPass] = useState("");
const [Response, setResponse] = useState("");

const userChange = (event) => {
    setName(event.target.value);
};

const passChange = (event) => {
    setPass(event.target.value);
};

const login = () => {
    // login using Name and Pass
    setResponse("server response")
}

return (
    <ThemeComponent>
        <TextField label={"user"} onchange={userChange} />
        <TextField label={"pass"} onchange={passChange} />
        {Response}
        <Button onClick={login} text="LOGIN">LOGIN</Button>
    </ThemeComponent>
)
```